# Когда использую конструкцию where exist and not exist, sql игнорирует мои where

Tags: sql

Имею такой запрос, используя запрос ниже пытаюсь получить записи которые имеют в таблице один значения `column1 = 3, column2 = 0, column3 = 0`, и соответственно в связанной таблице либо имеет значение 111, либо чтобы запись была не связанная через pivot. В результате запроса, получается такая картина, что `where exist`  отрабатывает, а вот поиск по колонкам `column1, column2, column3` не срабатывает. Прошу помочь решить данную проблему, спасибо.

```
select * from table1 where column1 = 3 and column2 = 0 and column3 = 0 and not exists (select * from table3 inner join table_pivot on table3.id = table_pivot.license_column where table1.id = table_pivot.system_id) or exists (select * from table3 inner join table_pivot on table3.id = table_pivot.license_column where table1.id = table_pivot.system_id and license_column = 111)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, поставьте скобки:

```
select ... where ... and (not exists ... or exists ...)
```

Без скобок получается, что `and` срабатывает только между вашим условием на колонки и `not exists`, а условие `exists` проверяется само по себе и если оно выполнено, то строка попадает в выборку, условие на колонки не проверяется, т.е. получается как будто скобки стоят так:

```
select ... where (... and not exists ...) or exists ...
```

Это получается в частности потому, что у "логического и" `and` приоритет выше, чем у "логического или" `or`.